# Ampps and xampp installation in the same remote server

Tags: xampp, ampps

Is it possible to install ampps and xampp in the same remote server on linux? For instance I have xampp installed in `/`and I will install ampps in `/mnt`. Do I have to do any configs to change the listening ports?

Comment: Not sure, go and give it a try. Certainly you can install it, though `/mnt` is the wrong place for such things. I would suggest `/opt/ampps` instead. And you will definitely need to reconfigure it, since it's components will collide with those of the other installation when they try to bind to the privileged ports (http server port 80, mysql server port 3306 and so on), so you will have to configure non standard ports.

Comment: However ask yourself this question before going to work: why would you want to do that? I never even understood why people install the `xampp` package on Linux systems, it's components are available with a single click in the software management anyway and then in a form that is integrated into your system much better than such a third party recompilation of packages.

Comment: If I could I wouldn't install ampps. Yet my disk is full, so I bought another one and mounted it in /mnt. So that I can use this additional space, this is the only solution I found to keep working

Comment: But why would adding diskspace mean that you need to install another software package?!?

Comment: I'm a newbie and at this level, I don't how to deal with this. I added this disk to have more space in my remote server. Now that it's added I don't know how to use it. The partition, I'm working on is full. I started having mysql issues in my applications. I have 100 Go in this disk that I don't know how to use it, if you see what I mean.

Comment: Let's chat a bit here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/185470/ampps-and-xampp-installation-in-the-same-remote-server?tab=general